# Add async data to QTableView with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-asyncio

I would like to add async data to a QTableView without blocking and showing a fallback text like "Loading..." in the cell while it's retrieving the data.

I wonder if it's even possible with PyQt5...

That's what I have at the moment and obviously it doesn't work:

```py
import asyncio
import random
import string
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Item:
    @property
    def name(self):
        return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10))
    
    async def get_data_from_slow_api(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        return "Lorem ipsum"


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        item1 = Item()
        item2 = Item()
        item3 = Item()
        item4 = Item()
        data = [
            [item1.name, item1.get_data_from_slow_api()],
            [item2.name, item2.get_data_from_slow_api()],
            [item3.name, item3.get_data_from_slow_api()],
            [item4.name, item4.get_data_from_slow_api()],
        ]
        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Qt does not support asyncio but there are libraries that implement the logic to enable it as asyncqt or qasync. Considering the above, you also have to override the setData method that allows updating the items, and also implement a method that updates all the information. Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import asyncio
import random
import string
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from asyncqt import QEventLoop
# from qasync import QEventLoop


class Item:
    @property
    def name(self):
        return "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10))

    async def get_data_from_slow_api(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        return "Lorem ipsum"


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        if data is None:
            data = []
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if (
            role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole
            and 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount()
            and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount()
        ):
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if (
            role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole
            and 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount()
            and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount()
        ):
            self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, (role,))

    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        try:
            return len(self._data)
        except:
            return 0

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        try:
            return len(self._data[0])
        except:
            return 0

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._data = data
        self.endResetModel()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.model = TableModel()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        asyncio.ensure_future(self.fill_model())

    async def fill_model(self):
        data = []
        items = [Item() for _ in range(4)]
        data = [[item.name, "Loading..."] for item in items]
        self.model.set_data(data)

        await asyncio.gather(
            *(self.update_row(row, item) for row, item in enumerate(items))
        )

    async def update_row(self, row, item):
        value = await item.get_data_from_slow_api()
        index = self.model.index(row, 1)
        self.model.setData(index, value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    with loop:
        loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Do you know how to use something else than text in the table? I tried to put QCheckBox() and QIcon() but it doesn't output anything, and I have no error.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to avoid blocking the window when update_row() is running?

Comment: @0lan 1) The problem is that your model does not implement the roles related to icons and checkbox. That problem is out of the question so I will not continue answering on that topic.  2) Does my code generate that lock or have you modified my code? I have tested my code and I don't see that problem.